# Modal password page, if correct save with cookie

Tags: javascript, session-cookies, password-protection

I've got this modal password page to work great. I just need to password to save as a cookie or per session if it's entered correct. If there are thoughts about how to do this better, please let me know.

```
var passProtect = {
  id: $("#password_input"),
  key: "tlf",
  errorMessage: "Sorry, please try again",
errorState: function () {
    passProtect.id.css("border", "1px solid rgb(255,0,0)");
    $(".password-container .label").html(passProtect.errorMessage);
  },
  successMessage: "Success!",
  successState: function () {
    passProtect.id.css("border", "1px solid rgb(0,200,100)");
    $(".password-container .label").html(passProtect.successMessage);
  },
  prompt: "Please enter password"
};

function openUp() {
  $("#password-modal").fadeOut(250);
}

function checkPassword() {
  var passVal = passProtect.id.val();

  if (passVal === passProtect.key) {
    passProtect.successState(openUp());
  } else {
    passProtect.errorState();
  }
}

function bindEvents() {
  passProtect.id.on("keyup", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      checkPassword();
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  bindEvents();
});
```

Comment: what have you tried? did you google session storage and look up how the api works? it's a single line of line of code - doesn't really justify making a post for it.

Comment: by the way, don't store passwords in session storage, or at all on the client side.

Comment: the only way to do sessions properly is by storing them on the server, preferably encoded/encrypted and in some kind of database.

Comment: "it's a single line of line of code" Can anyone help give me an example? This is for a class project.

Comment: what youre trying to do is bad. people generally arent eager to help people do bad things. instead of trying to store a password on the client side, explain the problem that you're trying to solve by doing that and you will get more responses. however, if you insist on doing this terrible thing you're trying to do, it is literally a single line of code to store something in session storage or local storage, and you can get that single line of code from 15 seconds of googling.

Comment: it's just a shame it took 24 hours instead of 15 seconds. oh well.. lesson learned.. hopefully.